# Javascript Date, loop around to original date when over one year?

Tags: javascript, date

not sure how exactly to phrase this question, but I want to basically "loop around" a date, when it's more than a base date

What does that mean?

Let's say my start date is 7/7/2021

And let's say that the input date is one year later than 7/7/2021 [not sure exactly due to leap years [in other cases] etc, but] let's say that's 7/9/2022

since it's more than a year, I want to "loop back" to the original date, and add the remainder [if that makes sense], so in this case the result would be

7/9/2021

basically, it finds the remainder after taking into account the extra year, if that makes sense

another example, say my base date is the same, and my input is

7/10/2026 [without leap years for now]

then the output should give

7/10/2021

because it's more than a year etc...

obviously in these cases I can simply subtract the years and keep the dates, but I don't know how to calculate it for different months and different days, while taking into account DLS and leap years etc...

so far I was able to come up with this function for calculating the difference of days between two dates with timezone offsets, based on other answers from here on similar questions, but I don't know how to apply it to the above case [obviously I can simply check the amount of times of differences for, say, 365 days between each one, but that wouldn't take nito account leap years...]

```js
var yoymaweemBayn = (w, e) => {
    var d1 = new Date(w)
    var d2 = new Date(e)
    var day2 = (d2 - d1) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24
    var ac = day2 - (d2.getTimezoneOffset() - d1.getTimezoneOffset()) / (60 * 24)
    return ac
}

k.onclick = () => {
  ok.innerHTML = yoymaweemBayn(
    d2.value,
    d3.value
  )
}
```

```html
B"H
<br>
<input id=d2 value="7/7/2021">
<input id=d3 value="4/6/2023"><br>
<button id="k">Calculate?!</button>
<div id=ok></div>
```

To clarify:

How do I subtract a certain number of years from the latter date, until the date "loops back around" to be within the base year, while taking into account leap years [such that its not always 365 days apart]?

Comment: Daylight savings just changes the hour, so aren't you only interested in leap years? And if so, isn't it just as simple as checking if the input date is 2/29/XX?

Comment: @David yeah mainly leap years is what I meant, what do u mean by the last part I'm confused [how would that work for difference days of the month etc]

Comment: @David meaning how do I subtract a certain number of years from the latter date, until the date "loops back around" to be within the base year, while taking into account leap years [such that its not always 365 days apart]?

Comment: Maybe I'm not fully understanding your question but it seems to me that if the date is anything other than 2/29, you can just make the year the same as the start date's year, and if it is 2/29, you change the year, but if the start date's year % 4 == 0, you leave it at 2/29, or if the start date's year % != 0, you make it 3/1.

Comment: Are you wanting the number of days in a year to effectively be 365 all the time? I'm just not understanding.

Comment: @David Im confused with "start date's year % 4 == 0", that means essentially that every 4th year is a leap year? I think I see, but if there were, say, 3 leap years within the two dates, then there would be more of a one day offset, how do I calculate that?

Comment: @David I want the input date, which is a few years later, to be "looped back around" within the base year while still keeping the same dates

basically I have a database of information that is organized by dates of the year starting from 7/7/2021 and going for a year, and I am able to search that data now by simply entering the current date, however I want to be able to search for the same data for new years, while keeping the same organized format if that makes sense, such that if someone is 2 years ahead and enters their current date it would give the same entry as today

Comment: Yes every 4th year is a leap year (unless the year is divisible by 100 and not divisible by 400). From the start date, you can calculate how many leap years happen between two dates by calculating the number of days since the last leap day (2/29) and adding that to the number of days that have passed and finally dividing that by the number of days between leap days, which is constant (unless you're talking about a new century, but for the purposes of this question, we'll keep it simple). That number is 1461 (4 years + 1 day). Truncate the decimal and you have the number of leap years.

Comment: @David Im confused with "calculating the number of days since the last leap day (2/29) and adding that to the number of days that have passed" what if the current date is before 2/29, or what if its not in a leap year, and what does it mean "to the number of daysthat have passed",  from what? my mind seems to not be working properly atm and am having trouble understanding "Truncate the decimal and you have the number of leap years." and when I have the number of leap years how do I use that to loop the end date back around

Comment: if the current date is 1/1/2018, you would calculate the number of days between 2/29/2016 and 1/1/2018. Let's call that X. You then calculate the number of days between 1/1/2018 and your start date. Call that Y. You add X to Y to get Z. Then you divide Z by the number of days between leap days, which is a fixed constant 1461. There are 1461 days between 2/29/2016 and 2/29/2020. Math.floor(Z/1461) is the number of leap days between your start date and your input date.

Comment: And again, 1461 breaks down slightly on century years which are not divisible by 400 (1700, 1800, 1900, 2100, etc.). Since those years are not leap years. You would have to account for that too, but for the sake of getting you started, I kept it simple.

Comment: Wondering whether it even makes sense to work based on number of days here, and if you might not be better off with `somedate.setFullYear(somedate.getFullYear()-1)` to move the date back by a year? If that is still greater than your input date - then go back another year. That method has an automatic handling of “overflows” built-in, if you start from `2020-02-29` and go one year back, you’ll land on `2019-03-01`.

Comment: So as an example, using the function you made to calculate the days between two dates, my start date is 12/8/2014, my input date is 1/1/2018. X = 672. Y = 1120. Z = 672 + 1120 = 1792. Math.floor(1792 / 1461) is 1, so there's 1 leap year between 12/8/2014 and 1/1/2018.

Comment: @David then how do I use the number of leap years to loop around the dates